# Get resourceName's for accounts in a Google Workspace via API

Tags: google-workspace, google-people-api

I am superadmin of a Google Workspace. I want to retrieve Google Contacts from several accounts of my workspace (accounts like `press@....org`, `donate@....org`).

For [doing that via the API call](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python) `googleapiclient.discovery.build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds).people().connections().list(resourceName=resourceName)` I need `resourceName`s for the accounts of interest.

I tried doing that by running in Python `googleapiclient.discovery.build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds).people().listDirectoryPeople(readMask= 'emailAddresses', sources= ['DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE'], pageSize= 1000).execute())`. During token retrieval I'm using `SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly']` and re-obtained the creds.

After doing that I received an error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:listDirectoryPeople?readMask=emailAddresses&sources=DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE&pageSize=1000&alt=json returned "The G Suite domain admin has disabled external directory sharing. See more details at https://support.google.com/a/answer/6343701". Details: "The G Suite domain admin has disabled external directory sharing. See more details at https://support.google.com/a/answer/6343701">
```

I went to https://support.google.com/a/answer/6343701 and as recommended switched to `Public data and authenticated user basic profile fields` in Directory settings. I waited 24 hours, but I'm still getting the same error.

What is the proper way to get `resourceName`s for the accounts I'm interested in?

In general, am I using the right API calls?

My endgoal is to [collect Google Contacts for these accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76907356/collect-all-google-contacts-from-certain-accounts-in-google-workspace-as-a-supe). I am superadmin, so I can set up any permissions needed, if I know what is needed :)

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is currently off, only is enabled `External Directory sharing > Public data and authenticated user basic profile fields`. Should I enable `Contact Sharing`?

Comment: Is contact sharing also enabled from Directory Settings \> Sharing Settings \> Contact Sharing. –

Comment: Yes, I'll provide a sample of the setting in my end as an answer

Comment: In the meanwhile I've made it work with `admin/directory_v1`, I then took one user from the output, and used its 21-digit `id` to try `...connections().list(resourceName f'people/{id}')` - this blew up with `Only "people/me" resource is supported`.

I also enabled `Contact Sharing` as you suggested, the error of `...people().listDirectoryPeople(readMask= 'emailAddresses', sources= ['DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE'], pageSize= 1000)` is still `The G Suite domain admin has disabled external directory sharing.`

Comment: Changing the setting may be also subject to propagation time as you have only made the change this instance. But for further testing, you can play with the API Explorer in the answer by using the Incognito Window in order to isolate any caching issues made on the change of the settings in the Admin Console.

Comment: I will wait for it to propagate and will report if it helps or not.

Any hints, how to work around `Only "people/me" resource is supported`? Is the 21-digit `id` from `admin/directory_v1` the `resourceName` I'm looking for?

Comment: It looks like the resourceName parameter is already deprecated based on this reference article: 

[https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) but let me try to play around this a little bit and get back to you if i find anything

Comment: Hmm, indeed it's documented that only `people/me` is supported. But how to retrieve Google Contacts userdata for the accounts of interest? (as a superadmin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

Enable the contact sharing option in your Directory Settings in the Admin Console. This option is possible for people.listDirectoryPeople for you to be able to list all domain profiles and domain contacts in the authenticated user's domain directory.

Sample:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Also, set the External Directory Sharing to Domain and Public Data.

[image]

You can also test this by running the API Sample on this [link](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/listDirectoryPeople)

Showing below that the execution was successful:

[image]

Comment: I've enabled `Contact Sharing` and still getting the same error 403, including in API explorer. `{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The G Suite domain admin has disabled external directory sharing. See more details at https://support.google.com/a/answer/6343701",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}`

Comment: There is also a small panel in the API explorer saying `This error may be due to using an insufficient credential type. Try using OAuth 2.0.`. I'm already using `OAuth 2.0`, not seeing if some `insufficient credential type` might be a problem...

Comment: I´ve updated my answer, can you try to do the updates I included in the answer?

Comment: I had already `External Directory Sharing` set as you propose, so it doesn’t change anything. I guess since only `people/me` is supported my question now becomes 1) how to get the Google Contacts of an account other than people/me?, 2) if needed, how to find the necessary id’s for this task?

Comment: So just to confirm, on the Contact Sharing option, it should be enabled and set to Show All Email Addresses and Show only Domain Profiles. And under the External Directory Sharing, it should be set to "Domain and Public Data", because based on your question, under "External Directory Sharing", it is set to "Public Data  and authenticated user basic profile fields", which is upon replicating, it seems that setting it to "Public Data  and authenticated user basic profile fields" is the root cause of error

Comment: Now, this should address the issue with the method people.listDirectoryPeople. But unfortunately, it looks like retrieving the contacts of other accounts within your organization is currently not possible

Comment: Well, I am the superadmin and the creator of the workspace. I can't see how this can be...

Comment: For now, I've looked into possible options starting with the Google Contacts UI (as a super admin), that currently there are no options to view the saved contacts of other accounts within the organization. And scanning through all documentations of People API, only Authenticated Users contacts can be retrieved using the API. Which, I currently propose that the feature to get the saved contacts of others is not possible. I'd suggest submitting a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191607&template=824105) instead.

Comment: I am wondering if I can use some sort of token impersonation to get contacts as if I was the other user.

Comment: I created a new question asking a more high-level advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76916369/obtain-other-google-workspace-accounts-google-contacts-using-api

Comment: Regarding `it seems that setting it to "Public Data and authenticated user basic profile fields" is the root cause of error`, I changed the setting according to your suggestions. And `listDirectoryPeople` worked! It does get me the resourceName's, as well as `admin/directory_v1` also works. Please update your answer, and I will mark it as accepted.

However, `resourceName`s are not useful for I did not know that for retrieving connections, `people/me` only works, so I created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76916369/obtain-other-google-workspace-accounts-google-contacts-using-api